# Is there actually an official w3c statement that states that user-agents actually had to return the tag name of elements in uppcase?

Tags: javascript, html

I find it odd that when we do `element.tagName`, all browsers (Chrome / FF / IE / Safari / Opera) consistently return the tag name in uppercase.

Is there actually an official w3c *statement* that states that user-agents actually had to return the tag name in uppcase?

Comment: @Jared so to rephrase, you are saying that there is no official specifications that state that such a rule had to be followed and user agents can choose to implement 100% standards-compliant code and at the same time not be obliged to return element.tagName in upper case?

Comment: My imagination would say that you are potentially correct, in lieu of other extant and specific instances that are answered/grounded in standardization.

Comment: Note, to be specific, unless I knew specifically otherwise, my answer would have been in an answer and not in a comment below the question.

Comment: @Jared: The case behavior of `e.tagName` is fully specified for both HTML and XML in the DOM Level 2 Core.

Comment: @mu - Where have you been all this night? My imagination was starting to get stressed...

Comment: @mu - I think you should reread my previous *comments*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [DOM Level-2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-104682815):

> **`tagName`** of type `DOMString`, readonly
>   The name of the element.
>   [...]
>   Note that this is case-preserving in XML, as are all of the operations of the DOM. The HTML DOM returns the `tagName` of an HTML element in the canonical uppercase form, regardless of the case in the source HTML document.

So `e.tagName` should **always** be upper case for HTML but the case will match the source document for XML.

Comment: thanks for the help. btw by *canonical* you do mean only a-z becomes A-Z and everything else remains as they are?

Comment: @Pacerier: Sort of. I suspect that if you put a `<μ>` tag in your HTML then you'd get `'Μ'` (that's an upper case Greek *mu*, not an upper case *m*) as the `tagName`. However, `<μ>` isn't valid HTML so you'd be on your own with stuff like that.

Comment: @Pacerier – "canonical" means defined or standard, so in the quoted text it means that if a character has a standard upper case form, then that is used. You only need to consider characters that are valid in HTML element names, which are only the letters A to Z and numbers 0 to 9. Numbers don't have an upper case form, so you don't need to worry about them.

Comment: @RobG ok i got that part about not having to worry about it. but i still cannot understand what do you mean when you say when a character has a *standard upper case form*

Comment: @mu_is_too_short i do know the meaning of canonical.. but when you say *standard* upper-case form, what exactly is the *standard*? who  defines the *standard*?

Comment: @Pacerier: They're just saying that upper case is the canonical form. Standards documents are full of stuff like that, it looks like English but it is actually Standardeze (just like contracts look like English but they actually written in Legaleze).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which specification you read.

As *mu is too short* commented (link to the DOM 2 Core [Element interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-104682815)), the DOM 2 Core spec says the tagName property should return HTML tagNames in upper case, however...

There was a time when XHTML was thought to be the future of HTML. At that time, it was proposed that in XHTML, all tag names should be in lower case. The [DOM HTML specification says in § 1.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-5353782642):

> Developers need to take two things into account when writing code that
>   works on both HTML and XHTML documents. When comparing element or
>   attribute names to strings, the string compare needs to be case
>   insensitive, or the element or attribute name needs to be converted
>   into lowercase before comparing against a lowercase string. Second,
>   when calling methods that are case insensitive when used on a HTML
>   document (such as getElementsByTagName() and namedItem()), the string
>   that is passed in should be lowercase.

So while tagNames might be returned in upper case in an HTML document, they must be returned in lower case in an XHTML document and in whatever case they are written in in an XML document.

It is considered good practice to convert all (X)HTML tagNames to lower case before using in comparisons, though I have never seen it recommended to convert names and IDs to lower case (other than in the specification referenced above).

Of course for all that XML-like markup, no one actually serves XHTML as XML on the web so it is just munged HTML. You can probably just compare with upper case tagnames (and hope you never get a real XHTML document), or use *toLowerCase* like the spec suggests.

Comment: The great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from. I tend to just downcase everything on both sides and if anyone uses mixed case in their XML elements, well, we have a word for people like that.

Comment: @mu is too short — I work with XML a lot where element names are mixed case, it's very common.

Comment: Really? I guess the word for those people is "common" then. I'm a bit surprised by that, glad I don't deal with that much XML anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Pacerier seems confused by upper case. You see, an "e" (regular) will uppercase to "E", but an "é" (with accent acute) should not. It should upper case to "É". So when they say it will upper case to the standard form, that's what they mean. So if you try to compare E with É, you won't get a match.